# Limit of itunes connect team single user can join

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Is there limit of `Developer portal` teams and `Itunes-Connect` teams single developer can join?

One team has limit of users. Has user limit of teams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only be part of 50 teams with a single user account/Apple ID. If you get an invite, you will get an error message that tells you, you need to "leave" other teams, before joining the new one.

Comment: It's nowhere mentioned in the docs, but I had the issue last week.